# Choose file and Input Text keyword not working in Robot Framework Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

`Choose File` and `Input Text` keyword not working in Robot Framework Selenium

What I have tried so far:

```
Choose File    xpath=//div[@id='dZUpload']    E:\\PPM_PDM_29_03_2019.xls 

Input Text     xpath=//div[@id='dZUpload']    E://PPM_PDM_29_03_2019.xls
```

I'm using `SeleniumLibrary`

Browser: `chrome`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What happens when you run the code you've provided? Why do you think it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium's upload file functionality does not work with a `<div>` element, it only works with an element that is an `<input type="file">`

Comment: So, is there any alternative way except `Input Text` and `Choose File`, although I have solved the problem by using `sikuli`

Comment: Generally yes, but it can get complicated fast.  It all depends on the implementation of the file uploader.  Most of them tend to fall into one of 2 categories: 1: they hide the <input type="file"> and use JavaScript to populate it (You can usually force the input element to become visible and use the Selenium send keys functionality). 2: They use some custom JavaScript handlers to perform file uploads (You can usually hook into it using a JavascriptExecutor and some help from the devs that wrote the code).